# What was the name of the fantasy book about a young woman with multiple colored hair that and that can change into a calico cat?

Tags: story-identification

I read a book back in the late 80's early 90's that told the story of a young woman who came from another place to live in this world. She could change into a calico cat and lived as a cat in this world for a while. She even had a kitten but it died. She fell in love with a painter who she posed for. He ends up unknowingly painting the hidden image of a cat in every painting he did of her.

Later, at the end of the book, you find out that she is like royalty because she is a calico cat and that she must fight some big battle back in her world to save her people.She is helped by her boyfriend the painter, who paints images of the powerful cat goddess in order to drain her powers and defeat her.

Does anybody know the title or author of this book? I have wanted to reread it for so long and see if the author had any more books.

Comment: I remember reading this book in the same time frame.  For some reason I link it to Piers Anthony in my mind.  I believe who ever it was has a metaverse and I was expecting this book to be a part of it but was initially mildly disappointed when it wasnt but I remember I enjoyed it enough to read the whole thing.

Comment: You are exactly right, @Chad, it is a prequel to the series. :)

Answer (score 10):

This sounds like one of the books in the [Joe Grey Mysteries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Joe_Grey_Mysteries), namely *The Catswold Portal*

> This delightful fantasy posits a Netherworld located under modern California and peopled by humans, mythological creatures--including Harpies and Griffons--and shape-changers such as the Catswold, who can shift between cat and human forms. In this land where technology fails but magic works, Melissa, a young woman with no memory of her past, goes to the city of Affandar, ruled by the cruel Queen Siddonie, to learn her history. Taking a strange interest in Melissa, the queen teaches her magic spells far superior to those of the common people. From an imprisoned Harpy she sets free, Melissa learns she is heir to the Catswold throne, but for her disobedience she is turned into her cat form and cast forth in the upperworld. There she is taken in as a pet by artist Braden West, who, unaware of her true nature, falls in love with her. Then Melissa discovers how to regain her human form and returns to the Netherworld pursued by Braden.

From [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0060765402)